# Python TKinter create a drop-down list dependent on a selection from another drop down list

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to copy a category from one project to another one. For this I've created a simple GUI with three fields. 
For the projects I am currently having a static drop-down list. 
But for the categories, I want to have a drop-down list based on the Project chosen above. Somehow Tkinter does not recognize (or read) my input:

```
#get project FROM which the information gets copied
Label(screen, text = "From project").grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
proj_id=OptionMenu(screen, clicked_proj_from, '1001', '1002')
proj_id.grid(column=1, row=1)
project_from = clicked_proj_from.get()

#get project TO which the information gets copied
Label(screen, text = "To project").grid(column=0, row=2, padx=10, pady=10)proj_id=OptionMenu(screen, clicked_proj_to, '1001', '1002')
proj_id.grid(column=1, row=2)
project_to = clicked_proj_to.get() 

#get attribute category
clicked_attr=[]
attr=get_category(project_from)
for attribut in attr.items:
    clicked_attr.append(attribut.name)

variable.set(clicked_attr[0])

Label(screen, text = "Attribute_category").grid(column=0, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)
attr_cat = OptionMenu(screen, variable, *clicked_attr)
attr_cat.grid(column=1, row=3)
category = variable.get()

screen.mainloop()
```

One I write the 1001 and not just `project_from` here:

```
attr=get_category(project_from),
```

the code works, but otherwise I get an error that the value is missing.

How can I change this Code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is because you execute `project_from = clicked_proj_from.get()` right after initiated the `project from optionmenu`, `project_from` should be `None` as no option is selected at the moment.  You should do it inside the callback function assigned to option `command`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you execute `project_from = clicked_proj_from.get()` right after initiated the **"project from optionmenu"**, `project_from` should be `None` as no option is selected at the moment.

You should do it inside the callback function assigned to option `command`.  Below is an updated version of your code as an example:

```
# function will be executed when project from is changed
def on_project_change(project_from):
    attr = get_category(project_from)
    menu = attr_cat['menu']
    # clear the optionmenu
    menu.delete(0, 'end')
    # add new attribute to optionmenu
    for attribute in attr.items:
        menu.add_command(label=attribute.name, command=lambda val=attribute.name: variable.set(val))
    # reset optionmenu selection
    variable.set('')

screen = Tk()

clicked_proj_from = StringVar()
clicked_proj_to = StringVar()
variable = StringVar()

projects = ('1001', '1002')

Label(screen, text='From project').grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
OptionMenu(screen, clicked_proj_from, *projects, command=on_project_change).grid(row=1, column=1)

Label(screen, text='To project').grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
OptionMenu(screen, clicked_proj_to, *projects).grid(row=2, column=1)

Label(screen, text='Attribute categories').grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
attr_cat = OptionMenu(screen, variable, None)
attr_cat.grid(row=3, column=1)

screen.mainloop()
```